# Compress/minify dynamically generated html with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there is a way to compress generated html markup, including style tags and more.

I tried with `.trim()` but that doesn't seem to remove any spaces.
And using `trim()` would if working remove spaces, which would mess up the html itelf.

This is the result I get:

```
<style>
    #element{
       background: red;
    }
</style>

<div id="element">
    this is my element 
</div>
```

This is the desired result:

```
<style>#element{background: red;}</style> <div id="element"> this is my element </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can find an npm package for this purpose (for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier).

Comment: @maksimr thanks will look into this option.

Comment: `.trim()` is the same as `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')`, so it is working exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`trim` only removes spaces from the beginning and end of a string.
The usual solution is to serve html gzipped, which is much more effective and most servers support it.